# Obtain $_GET value have plus ('+') Character in PHP

Tags: php, get

I have this link:

```
www.mysite.com?a=abc+dfg
```

I would, in php, obtain the value: $_GET["a"].

But, in this way, i get the string "abc dfg", without the "+".

How can i do to get the entire value?

Comment: That *is* the entire value. If you want the plus sign to be preserved, you'll have to encode it in hexadecimal. Try `?a=abc%2Bdfg`

Comment: have you tried $string = urldecode($_GET['a']); ?

Comment: If you want to inspect the raw input and original encoding, that's in `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should encode somehow before create the URL. Take a look at this article at php manual website:

[URLEncode Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

PHPCode

```
echo urlencode("asd+bbb"); //asd%2Bbbb
```

and URLDecode to get the results properly:

[URLDecode Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

```
echo urldecode("asd%2Bbbb"); //asd+bbb
```

Answer (score 0):

**Before** you pass it to your website

```
www.mysite.com?a=abc+dfg
```

you have to add `"www.mysite.com?" . "a=" . urlencode($value);`

---

**After** that your data on address url should be like

```
www.mysite.com?a=asd%2Bbbb
```

---

when you GET

You can call with `urldecode($_GET["a"]);`

**The return** should be `abc+dfg`

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but i would like to differ with most of the answers posted.

If you have abc+dfg you need to perform function urlencode(abc+dfg) to it.

then you will be able to get the plus sign using $_GET('a').

If you perform urldecode() it will give you abc dfg, without + sign.

You can verify my answer based on below code:

The file is named test.php:

```
 <?php

$question = "abc+dfg";

$ques_enc = urlencode($question);
echo "url encode";
echo "<br>";

echo "<a href='test.php?ques=$ques_enc'>
View question encode</a> ";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

echo "no url encode";
echo "<br>";

echo "<a href='test.php?ques=$question'>
View question</a> ";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";


if(isset($_GET['ques'])){
  echo "no url decode";
  echo "<br>";

$ques = $_GET['ques'];
echo $ques;
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

}

if(isset($_GET['ques'])){

echo "url decode";

$ques = urldecode($_GET['ques']);
echo "<br>";

echo $ques;

}
```

Image with urlencode() clicked:
[image]

Image without urlencode() clicked:
[image]

As you can see from above if you encode and don't decode, you get the plus(+) sign.
If you don't encode  and don't decode, you don't get plus(+) sign

Answer (score -1):

The space is not a url friendly character.  PHP's urlencode() function converts spaces to +

Try using urldecode()

```
echo urldecode($_GET["a"]);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php